CSS - Dropdown menu positioning
The dropdown menu was (edit: is -> was) overflowing out of the screen (width-wise), after fixing it I'd like to know how to control the position of it better and how to make it so that it's position isn't relative to the div(.top-menu), but the dropdown button.
I'm pretty much a beginner with CSS and HTML as a whole, basically I don't understand the position/display values but that's not the point. Basically I've been reading W3School's documentation I guess? I saw the Horizontal navbar page, and decided to change how I did it before (using 1 big div element for the whole menu and then little div elements inside).
Afterwards, I tried to make a dropdown menu basically just copying how they did it and noticed a problem, as said before the dropdown menu is going out of the width of the screen and some other problems aswell.
CSS:


.top-menu {
  height: 1lh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: end;
  line-height: 6;
}

.top-menu a {
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul.navbar {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: auto;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #BBBBBB;
  min-width: 160px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateX(10%);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
}



HTML
    <div id="top-menu" class="top-menu">
      <ul class="navbar">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
        <li>e</li>
        <li>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <span>Mouse over me</span>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <p>Hello World!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>


There's also some JS code I copied from ChatGPT, but I don't think it does anything so I didn't include it.
The overflow problem is (kind of) fixed, basically the question is how would I control it's position (except with translateX() because I want it to be aligned), width/height.
Also I would like to know; I noticed the top: 0%;, and saw that the menu is actually positioning itself relative to the whole top bar instead of the dropdown button. Is there any fix?

"The dropdown menu is overflowing out of the screen (width-wise)," I guess I don't see it doing that here, am I missing something?

Yes, sorry, I'm fixing the problem while writing the question and it ends up like this.

Two things to update:

The padding being added to <li> elements is affecting the alignment/positioning of the .dropdown-content element. The .dropdown-content needs to consider this when being positioned.
The .dropdown display should be inline.

Working Example:
I only modified the .dropdown and .dropdown-content blocks:


.top-menu {
  height: 1lh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: end;
  line-height: 6;
}

.top-menu a {
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul.navbar {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: auto;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #BBBBBB;
  min-width: 160px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px;
  z-index: 1;
  right: -12px;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
}
<div id="top-menu" class="top-menu">
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
        <li>e</li>
        <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <span>Mouse over me</span>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <p>Hello World!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



A Better Approach:
It is better if you do not add padding to the <li> elements, but instead to the children within the <li> elements. You will then have an easier time aligning the dropdown.  See the example below.
Note: I did update the css to use flex-box (more modern approach). You can just focus on how I changed where the padding is applied. It would still apply to your original code.


.top-menu {
  
  /* css variable to keep padding consistent */
  --navbar-item-padding: 10px 12px;

  height: 100px;
  
  /* align children to the right */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  
  /* make nav 'sticky' to top */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.top-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: var(--navbar-item-padding);
}

ul.navbar {
  /* display children in a row (horizontally) */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center; /* remove if you want items to take full height */
  
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  /* vertically center content of li */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  margin-right: 10px; /* use margin instead of padding so it does not modify the actual li's width */
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative; /* required for children to use absolute positioning */
}

.dropdown .dropdown-label {
  /* pad the label iteself so that we don't add padding to the parent, thus the .dropdown-content element can be positioned accurately */
  padding: var(--navbar-item-padding); 
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #BBBBBB;
  min-width: 160px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%; /* move down an amount equal to 100% of the parent element's height */ 
  right: 0;  /* align right edge with right edge of parent */
  /* left: 0; /* align left edge with left edge of parent */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
 <div id="top-menu" class="top-menu">
      <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">e</a></li>
        <li>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown-label">Mouse over me</div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <p>Hello World!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>




This works best I'd say and answers the question completely. One thing that I'd point out is that it makes all li's take the full height of the navbar. I suppose it's because the height of navbar   = 1lh; and line height is 6 so it takes up a full line. How would you modify that so the li's have little uncolored space (margin?) on top and bottom? Also thank you  for the answer, much appreciated.
In case my english is too bad, here it is visually.

Added a specific height to the .top-menu css and align-items: center to the ul.navbar css.  Now the .top-menu has its own specific height (no longer based on the its children) and the child elements are all vertically aligned.  If you remove the align-items: center from .ul.navbar, the items will take up the full height again.

Works like a charm. Thanks a lot! I learned a lot from this post, also it looks like this now. I added some padding to the items and set dropdown content top: 151%; left: -49% and it's I'd say perfect now. Sure the numbers are a bit odd (and I don't understand why) but at least it works. Thanks once again

@user23546251 glad it was helpful :) The, seemingly, random percentages might be because you added padding to the <li> element or the .dropdown elements.

Change display: inline-block; to display: inline;. This will cause div.dropdown to take up only as much space as it's children. So the dropdown will appear at the bottom edge of "Mouse over me".


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .top-menu {
            height: 1lh;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: cadetblue;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0%;
            left: 0%;
            text-align: end;
            line-height: 6;
        }

        .top-menu a {
            padding-right: 25px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        .test {
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            top: 40%;
            left: 40%;
            color: whitesmoke;
            background-color: blue;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 100px;
            padding: 20px 10px;
        }

        ul.navbar {
            float: right;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding-right: 10px;
            width: auto;
        }

        li {
            display: inline;
            padding: 10px 12px;
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }

        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #BBBBBB;
            min-width: 160px;
            max-width: 100vw;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 12px;
            z-index: 1;
            right: 0;
            top: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            transform: translateX(10%);

        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
            width: fit-content;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="top-menu" class="top-menu">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>c</li>
            <li>d</li>
            <li>e</li>
            <li>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <span>Mouse over me</span>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <p>Hello World!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>




For me it doesn't work. Partially because of the min-width I suppose, but I don't mind the width, it's still lining up with the big div

@user23546251 I just added a snippet of the code you posted with display: inline-block; changed to display: inline; and it works as intended. It's possible you have conflicting styles elsewhere on your page.

For me it works like this after adding margin: 0; and top: 155%. https://imgur.com/a/angxBMS (and of course inline). Also, could you explain what that change does? @EricFrancis12
